# Ansible loop with vars_prompt and with_sequence

Tags: ansible

I have a question, can we pass a range of inputs with vars_prompt.
Can we achieve with_sequence

example:
From the below playbook, i am able to pass multiple port numbers split by ",".

```
prompt: Please enter the port name: 0/1,0/2,0/3,0/4,0/5
```

But when I want to pass the input of ports in a range.

```
prompt: Please enter the port name: 0/1-0/5
```

Do we have option how to run, will that works with nested loop

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: port_name
    prompt: Please enter the port name
    private: no

  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: "{{port_name}}"
      groups: dynamically_created_hosts
    with_items: "{{port_name.split(',')}}" 
  - name: Change port speed
    port_speed_change:
      switch_ip: "{{ip_address}}"
      user: "{{user}}"
      password: "{{password}}"
      checkmode: "{{ansible_check_mode}}"
      name: "{{items}}"
      speed: "{{port_speed}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible directly with a library, however, you can achieve your purpose in several ways, one is using lists and loops.

Please consider two elements in your input:

`I1/S1-I2/S2`

`I=Interface`
`S=Subport`

In order to achieve this without errors it is necesary to run 3 loops:

1. Add elements in a list from your `I1/S1 to I1/S_Max`
2. Add middle elements from `I_middle/0 to I_middle/S_Max`
3. Add last elements `I2/0 to I2/S2`

First of all you collect your `port_name` variable, it is really important that you respect the sinxtax of input string:

```
- name: port_name
  prompt: Please enter port name (format X/Y-X/Z, e.g 0/1-0/5)
  private: no
```

Create 1st loop:

```
####1st cycle, first port first sub_loop
#1st sub_loop, first entry subport to maximum subport
    - set_fact: port_sub_loop={{port_sub_loop|default([]) | union([item]) }}
      with_sequence: start="{{ S1 }}" end="{{ S_MAX }}"

    - name: Add first elements (first interface, first sub_loop)
      set_fact: ports="{{ ports|default([]) | union([item.0+'/'+item.1]) }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ I1 }}"
        - "{{ port_sub_loop }}"
```

2nd block is tricky, because it has to escape in case `I1 >= I2 -2`, you cannot use `when` condition with loops, so I decided to use a `block` with a `rescue`:

```
####2nd cycle, middle elements, subports are from 0 to S_MAX... There is a rescue because you cannot add a condition "with_sequence", in case I1 >= I2 -2 it will continue with rescue 

#Set port interfaces loop ignoring first and last port

    - name: run middle loop
      block:

          - set_fact: port_interfaces_middle={{port_interfaces_middle|default([]) | union([item]) }}
            with_sequence: start="{{ I1|int + 1 }}" end="{{ I2|int - 1 }}"

      #Set complete port sub_interfaces loop from 0 to S_MAX
          - set_fact: port_sub={{port_sub|default([]) | union([item]) }}
            with_sequence: start="0" end="{{ S_MAX }}"

#          - name: Add middle elements (next ports starting from subport 0)
          - set_fact: ports="{{ ports|default([]) | union([item.0+'/'+item.1]) }}"
            with_nested:
              - "{{ port_interfaces_middle }}"
              - "{{ port_sub }}"
      rescue:
          - debug: msg='Not executed middle block'
```

Last part add elements for last `I2`:

```
#Set last interface sub_loop, from 0 to S2
    - set_fact: port_sub_last={{port_sub_last|default([]) | union([item]) }}
      with_sequence: start="0" end="{{ S2 }}"

    - name: Add last elements (from last_interface)
      set_fact: ports="{{ ports|default([]) | union([item.0+'/'+item.1]) }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ I2 }}"
        - "{{ port_sub_last }}"
```

### *FINAL SCRIPT*

```
  vars_prompt:
    - name: port_name
      prompt: Please enter port name (format X/Y-X/Z, e.g 0/1-0/5)
      private: no

  tasks:
#Get first interface
    - set_fact: I1={{ port_name | regex_search("^\d+") | int }}
#Get second interface
    - set_fact: I2={{ port_name | regex_search("\-\d+") | regex_replace('^\-', '') | int }}
#Get first sub_interface
    - set_fact: S1={{ port_name | regex_search("\d+\-") | regex_replace('\-$', '') | int }}
#Get second sub_interface
    - set_fact: S2={{ port_name | regex_search("\d+$") | int }}

#Set highest/lowest subinterface value
    - set_fact: S_MAX="{{ S1 if (S1 >= S2) else S2 }}"
    - set_fact: S_MIN="{{ S1 if (S1 <= S2) else S2 }}"

####1st cycle, first port first sub_loop
#1st sub_loop, first entry subport to maximum subport
    - set_fact: port_sub_loop={{port_sub_loop|default([]) | union([item]) }}
      with_sequence: start="{{ S1 }}" end="{{ S_MAX }}"

    - name: Add first elements (first interface, first sub_loop)
      set_fact: ports="{{ ports|default([]) | union([item.0+'/'+item.1]) }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ I1 }}"
        - "{{ port_sub_loop }}"

####2nd cycle, middle elements, subports are from 0 to S_MAX... There is a rescue because you cannot add a condition "with_sequence", in case I1 >= I2 -2 it will continue with rescue 

#Set port interfaces loop ignoring first and last port

    - name: run middle loop
      block:

          - set_fact: port_interfaces_middle={{port_interfaces_middle|default([]) | union([item]) }}
            with_sequence: start="{{ I1|int + 1 }}" end="{{ I2|int - 1 }}"

      #Set complete port sub_interfaces loop from 0 to S_MAX
          - set_fact: port_sub={{port_sub|default([]) | union([item]) }}
            with_sequence: start="0" end="{{ S_MAX }}"

#          - name: Add middle elements (next ports starting from subport 0)
          - set_fact: ports="{{ ports|default([]) | union([item.0+'/'+item.1]) }}"
            with_nested:
              - "{{ port_interfaces_middle }}"
              - "{{ port_sub }}"
      rescue:
          - debug: msg='Not executed middle block'


####3rd cycle, last port until last element

#Set last interface sub_loop, from 0 to S2
    - set_fact: port_sub_last={{port_sub_last|default([]) | union([item]) }}
      with_sequence: start="0" end="{{ S2 }}"

    - name: Add last elements (from last_interface)
      set_fact: ports="{{ ports|default([]) | union([item.0+'/'+item.1]) }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ I2 }}"
        - "{{ port_sub_last }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ ports }}"
```

I don't add `port_speed_change` cause it must be a local library, I don't know how you are using it.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for your detailed explanation. The above value is working fine if my input is 0/3-0/9. But when i give value 0/17-0/20 it is not working. It is giving a alert "to count backwards make stride negative"

Comment: You could use regular expressions to find your desired characters, but please remember to respect sintax... Also please if it works remember to select answer as valid... I update my response with new variables to extract desired values

Comment: To be more specific that will the above script will also work for the port numbers input 0/2-0/20

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question, I've decided to do it using 3 loops... Explained in the answer